# detects the combination between characters and numbers

Tags: python

hello guys im trying to figure this out but im completly stuck.
i have a text file. this text file contains as example IP's.

Network definines network and
host defines a client in a network

file:

```
network 192.168.12.0 <- theres is missing the subnetmask
host 192.168.12.1 <- theres is missng the subnetmask as well
```

now what i want to solve is. that the programm read the lines and detects the combination between characters and numbers and should attach the subnetmask after the ip either the “255. 255. 255. 0” or the “255. 255. 255. 255"

I know you can solve the problem with regex, but I’m so lost I know not at all how to start.

result in txt file should be:

```
network 192.168.12.0 255.255.255.0
host 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.255
```

my tries:

```
import re

with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("test.txt","r") as f:
    for line in lines:
        match = re.match(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", line)
        if match:
            f.write("WORKS")
            print("yey")
        else:
           pass
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. You want to check in the string before the IP is network or host ?

Comment: i want that he progamm search for "host" or "network" in combination with numbers splitted with . 
if the programm match this combination it should append at the same line after the number combination(IP) the subnetmask "255.255.255.255" for host and "255.255.255.0" for network


result in txt file:

network 192.168.12.0 255.255.255.0
host 192.168.12.1 255.255.255.255

Comment: Did you try something with regex ? could you provide some code you've tried ?

Comment: i tried something. i show you. i edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the number of dots in the string. If the number of dots is 3 that would mean that the subnet is missing which you can append after that

Comment: is this possible with regex?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Although I am not an expert in regex.